# Login issue in dotnetnuke

Tags: authentication, dotnetnuke

I want to login on my dotnetnuke hosted site, first i click on register button and enter username=musewerx, password, confirm password, display Name=Hassan Ali, email address=hasan.uok@gmail.com and click register button. but for login i enter username=musewerx and password a message occur

> You are not currently authorized to login to this site.

And, on the given link below.

> http://my.websecurestores.com/knowledgebase/3512/How-do-I-change-the-HOST-or-ADMIN-passwords-in-DotNetNuke.html

OR given video tutorial link

> www.youtube.com/watch?v=HHHwB8OaQXg

i'll see for login that, they enter for admin login username=admin & password=dnnadmin and for host login username=host and password=dnnhost. and i follow this link but i am not login from host or admin. So what i do for login on dnn

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find below lines on web config,

```
   >  <system.webServer>
    >     <modules>
    >       <remove name="UrlRoutingModule"/>    
    >     </modules>   
       </system.webServer>
```

and after that, replace above from below then everything works fine.

```
  >  <system.webServer>
    >     <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" >
    >       <remove name="UrlRoutingModule"/>    
    >     </modules>   
       </system.webServer>
```

Answer (score 1):

When you install DotNetNuke, you must define a superuser account which is named "host" by default on the older versions.
You also could create an admin account for the default portal which is named "admin" by default on the older versions.
On recents versions, you could choose the username you want to use for the administration.

If you use the register link, you could register yourself with default permissions depending on the current website configuration. The admin could disallow registration for example.

Regarding the message "You are not currently allowed to login on this site", I believe that your website is configured with registration in "private mode". It means that an admin have to validate your account.
If you have an admin account or a superuser account, you could change the current "registration mode" in the site settings (menu "Admin > Site Settings"). You also could validate your account using the menu "Admin > Users" to edit your new account.

Answer (score 0):

I assume your user is not `authorized for login` anymore, if this message appears (a user can be de-authorized in DNN - which means he can't login). If you have database access, you can try to change the `IsApproved` field to true in the `aspnet_Membership` table, and then restart the application.

A user usually gets un-authorized if there were a few unsuccessful login attempts.